# Can I use DBSCAN to non numeric data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan

I want to make clustering in java with dbscan implementation.
Can dbscan be applied to non numeric data (pair of numbers)?
If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a distance function.

In fact (GDBSCAN) you only need a binary function `isNeighbor(x,y)`.

> Jörg Sander, Martin Ester, Hans-Peter Kriegel und Xiaowei Xu: **Density-Based Clustering in Spatial Databases: The Algorithm GDBSCAN and Its Applications.** In: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery. 2. Auflage. Band 2. Springer, Berlin 1998, doi:10.1023/A:1009745219419